# Как написать метод для PUT и для PATCH?

Tags: python, django, request, django-rest-framework

Необходимо реализовать PUT и PATCH методы. именно и то и другое.

Прочел, что PUT должен очистить не переданные ему аргументы, а PATCH именно внесет изменения в указанное поле. Данный метод работает как PATCH.

**Вырезка из ТЗ**
[image: URLS]
[image: ROUS]
[image: WOUS]

Это только часть кода, касающаяся PUT и PATCH, по ТЗ должна быть реализована вся CRUD, с токен аутентификацией. Все это уже реализовано, осталось только разобраться с PUT/PATCH. Поэтому это не весь код, а лишь его часть

```
**serializers.py**

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField()


    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            'id',
            'username',
            'is_active',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'last_login',
            'is_superuser',
        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.is_active = validated_data.get('is_active', instance.is_active)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

```
**views.py**

class UserViewSet(ListAPIView):

    # Allow only authenticated users to access this urls
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

def patch(self, request, **kwargs):
        saved_user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        data = request.data
        serializer = UserSerializer(instance=saved_user, data=data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            saved_user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "success": f"User with username '{saved_user}' updated successfully"})
```

**Как написать метод для PUT ?**

как я понял, если передать Postman-ом `PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/6/` *{"first_name": "Lama"}* , остальные поля, не указанные в теле запроса, должны очиститься...

Comment: Как то я не совсем понял) `ReadOnlyUserSerializer ` в моем понимании должен быть только для чтения и никак не для обновления данных

Comment: Вы правы, с нейминг не корректный, потому что пилю эту апишку уже долго(это первый опыт DRF), поэтому уже 100500 раз все переделывал и пока экспериментирую не меняю какие-то вещи для экономии времени...согласен стоило это поправить перед публикацией вопроса

Comment: Попробуй наследоваться от RetrieveUpdateAPIView.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что сериализатор можно упростить до

```
**serializers.py**

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            'id',
            'username',
            'is_active',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'last_login',
            'is_superuser',
        ]
```

А ваше представление изменить на

```
**views.py**

from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer


router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet)
```

Ну и добавить роутер в `urlpatterns`

```
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Comment: Хотя такие филды как `is_active `, `last_name `, `last_login ` и `is_superuser ` я бы помести в `read_only_fields`

Comment: да в ТЗ есть требование по read_only, но здесь не стал писать для краткости

Comment: Я добавил вырезку из ТЗ, по нему PUT PATCH и POST должны приниматься по primary key из урла

Comment: @Py_DG по вашей вырезке POST ничего не принимает из url